# Sort Rows in Excel?

Tags: sorting, excel, pivot-table, vba

I have an issue with an excel spreadsheet I want to see if I can do without VBA just because it seems easier to implement that way. Basically, there are many columns in the sheet I want to sort. However, I merely want to look at three columns: the title column, the data column and the status column.

In a new spreadsheet, there will be four sections. Each section corresponds to 3 months of the year (ie Jan, Feb, Mar. will map to the first column on the new spreadsheet, April, May, June will map to the second column on the new spreadsheet).

Based on the date, and if the status column has the word "Finished" (in the original spreadsheet), I want to map the title to a certain column under the new spreadsheet based on the date criteria as described in the previous paragraph. So for example, if the original spreadsheet has following:

```
Title Date Status

Doc1 1/12/13 Finished
Doc2 2/10/13 UnFinished
Doc3 4/1/13  Finished
Doc4 3/31/13 Finished
```

Would map to, on the new spreadsheet:

```
1st Column | 2nd Column
Doc1         Doc3 
Doc4
```

I have looked a lot into pivot tables but I can't "automate it" as much as I want to. I have gotten it down to the point where I can change the pivot tables into filtering based on date, but I want it even more automated than that. I've also tried excel formulas but that has been to no avail. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Would this pivotTable meet your needs? 
A pivottable that has a group for each quarter (3 months in the year). When you expand that group, you can see the names of the docs in that quarter (Doc1 and Doc4 would appear under Q1 for example).

Comment: I think this pivot table would definitely fit my neets @Jaycal. Would the pivot table automatically sort for me which titles when into which columns? I'm fairly new to excel though so would you have any ideas on how to do so? And pnuts could you elaborate a bit on your explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a PivotTable it seems fairly easy to 'automate' as far as Sheet `2` as below:

[image: SO17864374 example]

but from there to the result requested is relatively 'manual' without VBA, so may not suit.

For my convenience I have changed the date formats. The PivotTable is constructed as usual/indicated without showing grand totals for rows or for columns (PivotTable Options, Totals & Filters). The Column Labels are `Date` with Grouping By Quarters with appropriate Starting at: and Ending at: (Group) and Collapse Entire Field (Expand/Collapse).

The formula in `I6` is to convert the document count (always 1) to document name:

> =IF(F6=1,$E6,"")

However, to allow room for additional quarters in the PivotTable the formula should be moved to the right. The formula would need to be copied across and down as necessary.

The process becomes more ‘manual’ with copying the results of these formulae, pasting them (with Special / Values) into a new location (in the example 2!A1) and, if required, deleting blanks.

Comment: Sure, that is fine. I can delete some of my comments also. I just dont understand why my dates won't group. It says "Cannot group that selection" when I right click the dates that pop up after putting Dates into the Column Labels area of the Pivot Table.

Comment: I think in my document they are strings. When I try to edit them, it simply shows up as 3/30/2013 for example and displayed on the spreadsheet is also 3/30/2013. Should I try to change them into numbers?

Comment: Okay, so change the dates from strings to numbers. Ill respond to this when I get this done! thanks for your help!

Comment: hey I actually got everything to work! Thank you so much! I just have one issue now--I want it so that when I refresh my pivot table, I am able to see new and more items in the table. However, when I add in a date in the source data that doesn't correspond to any of the dates in the Qtr1 group, my pivot table simply creates a new column for it. For example, If I wanted to put a date like 12/02/13 into Q1, I can't because it is not in the group of Qtr 1 when it was originally made. Is there a way to expand the grouping of Qtr 1 so it includes the start and ends of all months specified?

Answer (score 0):

This may be against the rules with regards to maintaining the integrity of the OP's request, but hopefully it doesn't offend :)

Here's another option.

1. Add another column (shame on me, I know) to the original data, and
   called this Quarter. The formula that goes next to the existing data
   is the following.

   ```
   =IF(C2="Finished",IF(MONTH(B2)<=3,"Q1",IF(MONTH(B2)<=6,
       "Q2",IF(MONTH(B2)<=9,"Q3","Q4"))),C2)
   ```

   Basically, if the status is "Finished", then determine in what quarter the date is.
2. Create the pivot table with that data, and then add "Quarter" and
   "Title" to the Row Labels (in that order)
3. Last thing would be to click the arrow next to "Row Labels"  and select "Does not Equal" under "Label Filters". There you'll type "Unfinished" (no quotation marks). This will give you something like the image below.

[image: Another option using a formula and PivotTables]

From here the only manual thing you'll need to do is update the data range for the pivot table if more rows are added to the pivot table data and refresh the pivot table if the original data changes

NOTE: To address your question about sorting; after you do the steps above, you can select the Row Labels again and do an A>Z sort to get each quarter to be sorted in alphabetical order

Comment: Great! Thanks for this! I will try this out if the previous answer doesn't work.